# Distributing iPhone Ad Hoc Updates

Tags: iphone, installation, adhoc

I am using ad hoc distribution to run a beta test program and have run into a couple issues with distributing app updates.  The only way I have been able to get an app update on a device through ad hoc distribution is to delete the app from the device first and then install the update.  This adds extra steps for beta testers and erases their app settings.

Is there a way to install an ad hoc update without deleting the app from the device?  If not, is their a way to preserve the user's settings for the app?

Thanks for any help.  This is a huge frustration right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet it's your version number.  First time I ever did an Ad Hoc update (as opposed to the first revision) I forgot to increment the version number in the plist.